# VideoJS dynamic source change via RESTful API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, video, html5-video

I have got the following problem.
We have got a AngularJS app wich should server a video when on the route example.com/video/:id
It calls the API we have written completely correct and the file url we get back is completely correct.
Now we of course want to show this video inside VideoJS.
We are constructing the JSON as String like this:

```
var video_sources = '[{ type: "video/mp4", src: "http://example.com/'+data.data.filename+'-360.mp4" }';
        video_sources=video_sources+"]";
```

The String we get is the following:

```
[{ type: "video/mp4", src: "http://example.com/clip-360.mp4" }]
```

Now we use the .src() method of VideoJS to change the sources like this:

```
video_player.src(video_sources);
```

but now we get a VideoJS error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Tb' of null {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'Tb' of null"}message: "Cannot read property 'Tb' of null"
```

I cannot figure out why it is not working.
Some information on the player:
When the user visits the site the player is already loaded but not visible. It also has got no videos included if this important but I do not think so.

Comment: how is the video_player object created - inline or in a directive?  What DOM node is it bound to?  How do you make the video player not visible initially (ng-if, ng-show)?  Probably need to see more code.

Comment: this is NOT a laravel issue.

Comment: We have got a script tag in the index.html which does this: var video_player = videojs('example_player'); We listen for route changes and the and display block instead of display none. We use Laravel for the API but yes sorry it is not really important for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!
I just provided a Object instead of a String and it worked